# Question on work and springs

Tags: calculus

I'm very confused doing my math homework, and I'm not sure if my professor had made a typo but here's the question:

Find the work done in stretching a spring from resting to t meters.

I thought you needed the distance, and the spring constant to answer the question.

Comment: Yes you're right you do need more information (distance from equilibrium point, and spring constant for the system), that is to say if your professor was expecting a numerical answer.

Answer (score 0):

Notice,

Let $k\ \left(\text{in }\ N/m\right)$  be the stiffness of the spring.

The spring is initially in the rest. Now it is stretched/elongated  by a length  say $x$ then the (resisting) spring force in the stretched form $$F_x=\text{(stiffness)}\times \text{(displacement)}=kx$$
Now, the spring is further stretched/elongated  by an elementary length $dx$ then the elementary work done on the spring $$dW=\text{(Spring force},\ F_x)\times (\text{elementary displacement/elongation},\ dx)$$ $$=(kx)(dx)$$ 
$$dW=kxdx$$ Hence, using integration the total work done on the spring to stretch it from rest $(x=0)$ to a length $x=t$ $$\int dW=\int_{0}^{t}kx dx$$
$$W=k \int_{0}^{t}x dx$$  $$=k \left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{t}$$  $$=k \left[\frac{t^2}{2}-0\right]$$$$=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}kt^2}$$